# Accessing artifact from Task container

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, docker-container

I am trying to integrate a pipeline with Veracode (which uses a Java `jar` file in the pipeline process) but don't want to install Java on the agent. Rather I am just using a container to run the command in like so:

```
resources:
  containers:
    - container: java
      image: somepackagerepo.com/java-build

  ...(omitted)

  - script: |
       curl -sSO https://downloads.veracode.com/securityscan/pipeline-scan-LATEST.zip
       unzip -o pipeline-scan-LATEST.zip
       java -jar pipeline-scan.jar -vid $(ID) -vkey $(SECRET) -f $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\MyApi || true
    target:
    container: java
    displayName: Run Veracode Scan
```

The issue is I always end up getting

> Insufficient permissions to read file: '/__w/6/aMyApi

(not sure what the `a` in front of the `MyApi` comes from?)

I figure that the container that the command is running in is having an issue reading the artifact that is published in the `$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` area on the agent. Is there a way that I can copy my artifact down into my container or change permissions so it can be able to read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Insufficient permissions to read file: '/__w/6/aMyApi

The `a` in front of the `MyApi` is from the Pipeline variable: `$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

The value of the variable is : `/__w/6/a`.

It doesn't seem to miss the `\` in your command. You can change to use `\\` in Ubuntu System.

For example:

```
java -jar pipeline-scan.jar -vid $(ID) -vkey $(SECRET) -f $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\MyApi || true
```